# MySQL Run SQL Script in Command Prompt to create table and master data - Error

Tags: mysql, database, bash

I have created a table in MySQL and have the SQL script handy to create all the tables ans master data. However, i tried all possible way but it is not letting me to do so.

From the command prompt, i connected to mysql by passing this

```
>mysql -localhost -root -p;
mysql> Use MYDB
mysql> source d:\script\test.sql
```

it is giving me a message which i don't understand, please help.

[image]

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.20, for Win64 (x86_64)

Connection id:          22
Current database:       oyeohdb
Current user:           dms@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 1 hour 13 min 34 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 99  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 68  Flush tables: 1  Open tab
les: 61  Queries per second avg: 0.022
--------------

Outfile disabled.
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'D:criptest.sql', error: 2
mysql> SOURCE D:/script/test.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=
MyISAM' at line 10
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is MySQL's escape character in strings. You should either double it or use forward slash:

```
mysql> source d:\\script\\test.sql

mysql> d:/script/test.sql
```

Comment: Thanks! but That didn't work. I tired and it given me below error. **bold**       mysql> source d:/script/test.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=
MyISAM' at line 10
mysql> source d:\\script\\test.sql;
ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=
MyISAM' at line 10 **bold**

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue and it was solved by running

```
mysql_upgrade.exe
```

Located at:

```
...bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin
```

I hope that this issue works out for you. Cheers!